# XSLT 3 how to write a package

Tags: xslt-3.0, oxygenxml

I tried to learn package then I started and copied the working example from the xslt 3 specification but I cannot use the package.
In the template where I use  I got an error:
The package cannot be found.

What did I do wrong? I expect something with name or xmlns declaration
The only thing I changed is http://example.com/csv-parser to http://flexibatch.com/fhx-parser and its related xmlns declaration.
Flexibatch.com is as fictional as example.com

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please tell us exactly which XSLT 3 processor you use, including its exact command line attributes or its IDE configuration. For Saxon 9 for instance, you need to provide the location of packages with the `-lib` option on the command line or in a configuration file.

Comment: I use Oxygen xml editor 21.1 with Saxon EE 9.8.0.12!built in or 9.9 external.

Comment: Sorry I do not know it’s attribute I will try to check with Oxygen

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Saxon 9 inside oXygen, then I think one option to use packages is the create and use a Saxon configuration file (oXygen supports creating that file type with new file -> Saxon configuration where you have an option to open the section [xsltPackages] where you can then relate the `name` of a package to a `sourceLocation` or `exportLocation`).

Then in the transformation scenario in the extended Saxon options you can specify the Saxon configuration file to use and that way Saxon will know how to find any package your main module uses with `xsl:use-package` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-use-package) because it can relate the URI/name given there to a package location.

It is a bit of a complicated setup, perhaps add a tag for oXygen so that their support guys see your question and can tell you any more or easier options.

An example section from a Saxon config file to use the package directly from the XSLT 3 test suite is

```
 <xsltPackages>
      <package name="http://example.com/csv-parser" version="1.0"
           sourceLocation="https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/raw/master/tests/decl/package/package-100.xsl"/>
 </xsltPackages>
```

of course you can adapt the source location if you have a local file and you need to adapt the name if you have done that as your question suggests.

The XSLT code to use that package is online viewable at https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/blob/master/tests/decl/package/package-100a.xsl (or executable/downloadable at https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/raw/master/tests/decl/package/package-100a.xsl) and is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:csv="http://example.com/csv"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs csv" version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- example input "file"  -->
    <xsl:variable name="input" as="xs:string"
        >name,id,postal code 
        "Abel Braaksma",34291,1210 KA
        "Anders Berglund",473892,9843 ZD</xsl:variable>

    <!-- entry point -->
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:copy-of select="csv:parse($input)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:use-package name="http://example.com/csv-parser" package-version="*"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So you could start a transformation scenario in oXygen with the XSLT code linked directly from https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/raw/master/tests/decl/package/package-100a.xsl and the Saxon 9 specific settings using a configuration file with the above section.

Comment: Thanks Martin i try that tonight

Answer (score 0):

It works with the config file but now I get an error message: « Cannot apply cascading transformation. Reason: .org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/..../Test-Package.xsl_xslt_cascade; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 9; Content not allowed in prolog. » (line 3 is xmlns:xsl=....)

Comment: Either start a new question with the necessary details (minimal but complete code samples of XML, XSLT files and the configuration file you have used) or edit your question and provide the details there. It might be better to start a new question if the problem now arises with your own code and is no longer about using and running package based XSLT 3 in oXygen in general.

Comment: Ok I do that but it will take some time as I am working now and only have my phone. Code is still the one from xslt 3 spec 3.5.7

Comment: Ok forget it I recopied the example from xslt 3 specification chapter 3.5.7 and it works so obviously I made an error in my previous trial. Thanks for your support Martin.